# Booting with different X settings

Tags: xorg, gpu, bumblebee

My laptop has the Optimus technology. In order to save battery life I run graphics out of my CPU and only turn the GPU on on occasions using bumblebee.

This works relatively well as long as I don't use the GPU often. But it's a pain when I'm constantly launching apps in optirun ...

Therefore I was wondering. Is there anyway to reboot with a `Enable GPU` option ? I use GRUB + GDM. GDM runs X so I'm guessing it's to late to select a specific X config ... And I don't have any idea of how I could do that at GRUB level.

Any idea on how to do such a thing ?